# A few problems on sup and nested intervals

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

I've been doing these 3 problems for a `proof´ oriented class, one i have found a solution (in fact has been asked here before but the threads are all closed), and checked a correct solution in the Analysis book from Apostol. The thing is, I think im making a mistake and i cant find it. The other 2 problems are using nested closed intervals and i dont really know where to start to solve them. Thanks for your help in advance, and here they go:

**The first one is**

If $A$, $B\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ are non empty and bounded above (so sup exists) we consider $A+B =\{a+b:a\in A,b\in B\}$. 
Show the relation between $sup(A)$ $sup(B)$ and $sup(A+B)$.

My solution:
First i show $A+B$ is bounded. Consider an arbitrary element of $A+B$ is of the form
$a+b$.

Now  $a \leq sup(A)$  and  $b \leq sup(B)$  from this we get

$a+b \leq sup(A) + sup(B)$. $  $ $ $ So $sup(A+B)$ exists, as $A+B$ is non-empty and bounded (completeness axiom). Also $sup(A+B) \leq sup(A)+sup(B)$ because $sup(A+B)$ is the smallest bound of the set.

Now i want to study the relation between supremums.

I know that for any $a+b$,

$a+b \leq sup(A+B)$ and hence $a \leq sup(A+B) - b$
So $sup(A+B)-b$ is an bound for $a$, and as $sup(A)$ is the supremum for any $a$
$sup(A) \leq sup(A+B) - b$

Doing the same for b, $b \leq sup(A+B) - sup(A)$ and as this is a above bound for $b$ and $sup(B)$ is the smallest one, $sup(B) \leq sup(A+B) - sup(A)$ then $sup(A) + sup(B) \leq sup(A+B)$ and $sup(A+B) \leq sup(A)+sup(B)$

And because of this $sup(A+B) = sup(A)+sup(B)$

**And here are the other two excercises that i really dont have idea where to start, specially the second one**

**Second one:**

Be $(I_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ a sequence of closed intervals and for every
$n\in\mathbb{N}$, be $\lambda_n$ the lenght of $I_n$; lets supose that $I_1\supseteq
I_2\supseteq\dots\supseteq I_n\supseteq I_{n+1}\supseteq\dots$. Show that 
$\lim \lambda_n$ exists and that if $\lim\lambda_n>0$ then
$\bigcap_{n\geq1}I_n$ is a closed interval of lenght $\lim\lambda_n$.

**My attemp to solution** For this one i know that they're not empty and bounded above and below (they're closed intervals) and i know that if two sets $A \subseteq B$ are bounded an non-empty, then $sup A \leq sup(B)$ and as they're closed $max(A) \leq max(B)$ and the same with their minimums so the lenght of $[P_n, Q_n]$ $|Pn-Qn|$ is decreasing.

**And the last one is**

Be $x_1$, $a\in\mathbb{R}$ Such that $x_1>0$ y $a>x_1^2+x_1$,
and for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ be $x_{n+1}=a/(1+x_n)$.
Then every interval **$[x_1,x_2]$, $[x_3,x_4]$**, $\dots$ and so on, form  an intersection of intervals and the only point in common $\xi$ common to every one of them is A root of the equation $x^2+x=a$.

**sugestion** (this comes with the excercise too)
Show that for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$$x_{n+1}-x_n$ and $x_n-x_{n-1}$ have opposite signs and that exists $\theta\in(0,1)$ such that $|{x_{n+1}-x_n}|\le\theta|{x_n-x_{n-1}}|$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: I may be missing something huge but I don't see how you get $\sup(A+B) \le \sup(A)+\sup(B)$ - just realized it's because $\sup(A) + \sup(B)$ is an upper bound - i would put that in there

Comment: @DanZimm thanks i forgot about putting that, edited.

Comment: @Amzoti Thanks! I though they were semi-related (as in they're in the same practice they gave me (sequences)) thats why i didnt split em up. About the second part i dont get what you mean by thoughts and I put part of my approach in 2 of 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: This is my first time putting a bit of effort into answering a post on MSE so I apologize in advanced if anything I write is false or unclear

1) Your proof seems fine to me other than justifying that $\sup(A+B) \le \sup(A) + \sup(B)$ (i.e. its an upper bound...)

2) First off, to show that $\lambda_n$ is decreasing I would observe that since $\{I_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of nested intervals $\exists \{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} , \{b_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} : I_n = [a_n , b_n]$ and it must be true that $a_n \le a_{n+1} \le b_{n+1} \le b_n$ so it's clear that $b_{n+1} - a_n \le b_n - a_n$ and $-a_n \ge -a_{n+1}$ so $b_{n+1} - a_{n+1} \le b_n - a_n$. We can see that $\lambda_n = b_n - a_n$ so $\{\lambda_n\}$ must be decreasing. Now if 
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \lambda_n = \lambda > 0
$$
then it's clear that $\lim_{n \to \infty} b_n - a_n = \lambda$. So it must be true that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = a , \lim_{n \to \infty} b_n = b$ where $a,b$ are finite and $\lambda = b - a$. now we observe that $\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} I_n = [a , b]$ (it's as if you take do $\lim_{n \to \infty} [a_n , b_n]$ - I've never seen this actually done, considering this isn't really a "limit" anymore) and then the length of $[a , b]$ is clearly $\lambda$.

3) Now I don't see exactly how to do this but it appears that this sequence oscillates between increasing and decreasing. I would try to notice a pattern with the oscillations between increasing and decreasing and then form subsequences so that you form this inequality $a_n \ge a_{n+1} \ge b_{n+1} \ge b_n$ and then form a sequence of nested intervals then the limit exists. From this you can pass the limit through your recursive definition so you get
$$
L = \frac{a}{L + 1} \iff L^2 + L - a = 0
$$
which shows that this sequence converges to the solution to the equation $x^2 + x = a$
I will keep thinking of how to find the proper subsequences here and update this answer accordingly

Hope this helps!

Comment: 2) for 2 i already had proof that they were decreasing. as in bn < bn-1 and an< an+1  but i didnt know what to do with that, take limit on an and bn and then propose that the lenght is lim bn-an and thats is lim lambda_n ?

Comment: @Aram you did, but this seemed like a more intuitive way to prove it's decreasing (note that I don't use this fact to prove what needed to be proved). I showed that $\lambda_n$ exists ($\lambda_n = b_n - a_n$, which both exist since it's a sequence of nested intervals). Next I showed that if $\lambda_n \to \lambda$ then $\lambda = b - a$ which will be the length of the final nested interval since the final interval will be $[a,b]$ (the intersection of a sequence of subsets will be equal to the smallest subset, which in our case is $[a,b]$).

Comment: It wasnt intuition, i mean in another excercise i had proof that if 2 sets one included in the other (A included in B for example) that were bounded, then sup (A) less or equal than sup(B), from this and knowing that the intervals were closed sets i could infer that the max and min of every set included in another one were less or equal and bigger or equal (for inf and min), thus max decreasing and min increasing. But i didnt know how to take the limit of that and then say that was lambda

Comment: @Aram ok, well in my opinion this seemed like a more intuitive approach - i apologize it doesn't seem the same way for you, and for overstepping where I should've helped. Anyways, do you see how I prove that the sequence $\lambda_n$ exists based on $a_n$ and $b_n$ and that $\lim \lambda_n = \lim b_n - a_n$?

Comment: you dont need to apologize, in fact i didnt prove nothing about the sequence, just that an was increasing and bn was decreasing, using something from another excercise i didnt post. I also just wanted to know where i was doing 'intuition' as the goal of the course this excercise comes from is writing every proof i need to proove as formal (or correct) as possible.

Comment: @Aram sounds good, was this rigorous enough? I apologize I was unable to help very much with number 3

Answer (score 0):

Put $I_{n}:=[a_{n},b_{n}]$; as the intervals are nested you get that $(a_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is increasing and similarly $(b_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is decreasing. Thus $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n=sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}a_{n}$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty}b_n=inf _{n \in \mathbb{N}}b_{n}$. From this we get $I:=\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} I_{n}=[a,b]$ where $a:=sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}a_{n}$ and $b:=inf _{n \in \mathbb{N}}b_{n}$ (you have to show that I is in fact an interval and that those are its two extremes). Moreover $ \lambda_{n}:=b_{n}-a_{n}$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty}\lambda_{n}=\lim_{n \to \infty}b_n - \lim_{n \to \infty}a_n=\lambda$ (by additivity of limits) where $\lambda$ is the lenght of I.